# SVG pie chart / interactive circle

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm creating a svg circle that has different segments, which will work like tabs for for showing/hiding content. It's basically a pie chart. I'm having trouble visually separating the segments I'm creating. I need it to stroke just from the center to the outside of the circle. I feel I need to figure out the stroke-dasharray attribute? Would love some help figuring out how to configure things.

My other ideas were to use a margin to offset the segmentPath function but the client wasn't loving the look of things. Finally had an idea to just add a separate line element to each segment - traveling from the edge of the circle to the center. Any help would be great.

```js
/**
 * Polar to Cartesian.
 * 
 * Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function polarToCartesian(x, y, r, degrees) {
    const radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return [x + (r * Math.cos(radians)), y + (r * Math.sin(radians))]
}

/**
 * Segment Path.
 * 
 * Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segmentPath(x, y, r0, r1, d0, d1) {
    const arc = Math.abs(d0 - d1) > 180 ? 1 : 0
    const point = (radius, degree) =>
        polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, degree)
            .map(n => n.toPrecision(5))
            .join(',')
    return [
        `M${point(r0, d0)}`,
        `A${r0},${r0},0,${arc},1,${point(r0, d1)}`,
        `L${point(r1, d1)}`,
        `A${r1},${r1},0,${arc},0,${point(r1, d0)}`,
        'Z',
    ].join('')
}

/**
 * Segment Function.
 * 
 * Modified version of Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segment(i, segments, size, radius, width, className, fillColor) {
    const center = size/2
    const degrees = 360 / segments
    const start = degrees * i
    const end = (degrees * (i + 1) + 1)
    const path = segmentPath(center, center, radius, radius-width, start, end); 
    const el = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path' );
    el.setAttribute(
        'd',
        path
    );
    el.classList.add( 'path-segment', className );
    el.style.fill = fillColor;

    return el;
}

/**
 * Render.
 * 
 * Function that will render the svg circle.
 */
function render() {
    // Circle Div.
    const circleDiv = document.getElementById( 'interactive-circle-svg' );

    if ( null !== circleDiv ) {

        // Setup environment.
        const svgSize = 580
        const segments = 6
        const segmentWidth = 60
        const outerFill = '#FB8D00'
        const middleFill = '#E68E36'
        const innerFill = '#F9B46F'

        // Set cirlce div attributes.
        circleDiv.style.height = svgSize + 'px';
        circleDiv.style.width = svgSize + 'px';
        circleDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${ 360/2 }deg)`
        circleDiv.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%'

        // SVG NS.
        const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        // Create the <svg>.
        const svg = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'svg' )
        svg.setAttribute( 'viewbox', `0 0 ${svgSize} ${svgSize}` );
        svg.setAttribute( 'overflow', 'visible' );
        svg.setAttribute( 'stroke', '#000' );
        svg.setAttribute( 'stroke-width', 3 );

        // Attach the children nodes.
        for ( let i = 0; i < segments; i++ ) {
            // Create the first <g>.
            let n = i + 1,
                radius1 = svgSize/2,
                radius2 = svgSize/2-segmentWidth+1,
                radius3 = svgSize/2-(segmentWidth*2)+2,
                g1 = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'g' );
            g1.classList.add( 'segment', `segment-${n}` );
            g1.setAttribute( 'data-segment-number', n );
            
            // Attach segments to the <g>.
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius1, segmentWidth, 'outer', outerFill ) );
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius2, segmentWidth, 'middle', middleFill ) );
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius3, segmentWidth, 'inner', innerFill ) );


            // Attach the <g> to the <svg>
            svg.appendChild( g1 );

            // Create event handlers with the g1.
            g1.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                const segNumber = this.getAttribute( 'data-segment-number' );

                // Hide bodies.
                const bodies = document.getElementsByClassName( 'segment-body' )
                for ( let i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( ! bodies[i].classList.contains( 'hide' ) ) {
                        bodies[i].classList.add( 'hide' );
                    }
                }

                // Show correct body.
                const body = document.getElementById( 'segment-body-' +  segNumber);
                body.classList.remove( 'hide' );
            });
        }

        // Attach to div.
        circleDiv.append( svg );
    }   
}

// Attach render to onload.
window.onload = render;
```

```html
<div id="interactive-circle-svg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that you use circles, mask them off and rotate them.

#### Update

After tweaking the SVG a bit you can now click each segment and get the ID. The SVG ends up being a bit more complicated in that each circle segment needs a stroke dash array on top of a mask also masking off, more or less, the same segment.

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.dataset.segmentNumber){
    console.log(e.target.dataset.segmentNumber);
  }
});
```

```css
use {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle r="35" stroke="white" stroke-width="25"
        pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="60 360"/>
      <line x1="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
      <line transform="rotate(60)" x1="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </mask>
    <g id="c1" stroke-width="10" fill="none" mask="url(#m1)">
      <circle r="45" stroke="#FB8D00"
        pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="60 360"/>
      <circle r="35.1" stroke="#E68E36"
        pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="60 360"/>
      <circle r="25.2" stroke="#F9B46F"
        pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="60 360"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 50)">
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="1" transform="rotate(0)" />
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="2" transform="rotate(60)" />
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="3" transform="rotate(120)" />
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="4" transform="rotate(180)" />
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="5" transform="rotate(240)" />
    <use href="#c1" data-segment-number="6" transform="rotate(300)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This does look excellent. I like the approach - however, how is it possible to target each "segment" here to work as tabs/toggles?

Comment: @MatthewEdiger In you own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78144042/322084 you are saying that using line elements is a bad idea because they are not perfectly straight. I know that yours are not, but in my answer the lines are fine. So, there is nothing wrong with my/this answer. If you have any further questions you can just comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that doesn't require guessing a value for stroke-dasharray, but requires trigonometry to explain the choices of angles.

I got the relevant angles after drawing a diagram of a "thick line" passing through the center of a circle.

[image]

There are different values for the angle depending on the radius.

Also, I changed `end` value in the `segment` function to `degrees * (i+1)` as the original interfered with the calculation somehow.

```js
/**
 * Polar to Cartesian.
 * 
 * Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function polarToCartesian(x, y, r, degrees) {
    const radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return [x + (r * Math.cos(radians)), y + (r * Math.sin(radians))]
}

/**
 * Segment Path.
 * 
 * Modified version of Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segmentPath(x, y, r0, r1, d0, d1) {
    const point = (radius, degree) =>
        polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, degree)
            .map(n => n.toPrecision(5))
            .join(',')


    let gapWidth = 12;

    let theta0 = Math.asin(gapWidth / (2 * r0)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    let theta1 = Math.asin(gapWidth / (2 * r1)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    const arc1 = Math.abs((d0 + theta0) - (d1 - theta0)) > 180 ? 1 : 0
    const arc2 = Math.abs((d0 + theta1) - (d1 - theta1)) > 180 ? 1 : 0

    return [
        `M${point(r0, d0 + theta0)}`,
        `A${r0},${r0},0,${arc1},1,${point(r0, d1 - theta0)}`,
        `L${point(r1, d1 - theta1)}`,
        `A${r1},${r1},0,${arc2},0,${point(r1, d0 + theta1)}`,
        'Z',
    ].join('')
}

/**
 * Segment Function.
 * 
 * Modified version of Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segment(i, segments, size, radius, width, className, fillColor) {
    const center = size / 2
    const degrees = 360 / segments
    const start = degrees * i
    const end = degrees * (i + 1)
    const path = segmentPath(center, center, radius, radius - width, start, end);
    const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    el.setAttribute(
        'd',
        path
    );
    el.classList.add('path-segment', className);
    el.style.fill = fillColor;

    return el;
}

/**
 * Render.
 * 
 * Function that will render the svg circle.
 */
function render() {
    // Circle Div.
    const circleDiv = document.getElementById('interactive-circle-svg');

    if (null !== circleDiv) {

        // Setup environment.
        const svgSize = 580
        const segments = 8
        const segmentWidth = 60
        const outerFill = '#FB8D00'
        const middleFill = '#E68E36'
        const innerFill = '#F9B46F'

        // Set cirlce div attributes.
        circleDiv.style.height = svgSize + 'px';
        circleDiv.style.width = svgSize + 'px';
        // circleDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${360 / 2}deg)`
        circleDiv.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%'

        // SVG NS.
        const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        // Create the <svg>.
        const svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg')
        svg.setAttribute('viewbox', `0 0 ${svgSize} ${svgSize}`);
        svg.setAttribute('overflow', 'visible');

        // Attach the children nodes.
        for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {

            // Create the first <g>.
            let n = i + 1,
                radius1 = svgSize / 2,
                radius2 = svgSize / 2 - segmentWidth + 1,
                radius3 = svgSize / 2 - (segmentWidth * 2) + 2,
                g1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'g');
            g1.classList.add('segment-body', `segment-${n}`);
            g1.setAttribute('id', 'segment-body-' + n)
            g1.setAttribute('data-segment-number', n);

            // Attach segments to the <g>.
            g1.appendChild(segment(i, segments, svgSize, radius1, segmentWidth, 'outer', outerFill));
            g1.appendChild(segment(i, segments, svgSize, radius2, segmentWidth, 'middle', middleFill));
            g1.appendChild(segment(i, segments, svgSize, radius3, 55, 'inner', innerFill));


            // Attach the <g> to the <svg>
            svg.appendChild(g1);

            // Create event handlers with the g1.
            g1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                const segNumber = this.getAttribute('data-segment-number');

                const bodies = document.getElementsByClassName('segment-body')
                for (let i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
                    if (!bodies[i].classList.contains('inactive')) {
                        bodies[i].classList.add('inactive');
                    }
                }

                // Show correct body.
                const body = document.getElementById('segment-body-' + segNumber);
                body.classList.remove('inactive');

            });
        }

        // Attach to div.
        circleDiv.append(svg);
    }
}

// Attach render to onload.
window.onload = render;
```

```css
.segment-body{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inactive{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="interactive-circle-svg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement required functionality, to add line element to each segment from center of circle to edge of circle, this code,

```
g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius3, segmentWidth, 'inner', innerFill ) );
```

should be replaced with this code,

```
g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius3, radius3, 'inner', innerFill ) );
```

It can be checked, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I now have 2 possible answers. One using an extra line element and one using margins. Neither is perfect. The line separators aren't perfectly straight. When using the margin method, the margin distance isn't consistent from the edge of the circle to the center. I'm leaning towards the margin method but tweaks would be welcome.

```js
/**
 * Polar to Cartesian.
 * 
 * Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function polarToCartesian(x, y, r, degrees) {
    const radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return [x + (r * Math.cos(radians)), y + (r * Math.sin(radians))]
}

/**
 * Segment Path.
 * 
 * Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segmentPath(x, y, r0, r1, d0, d1, i) {
    const arc = Math.abs(d0 - d1) > 180 ? 1 : 0
    const point = (radius, degree) =>
        polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, degree)
            .map(n => n.toPrecision(5))
            .join(',')
    return [
        `M${point(r0, d0)}`,
        `A${r0},${r0},0,${arc},1,${point(r0, d1)}`,
        `L${point(r1, d1)}`,
        `A${r1},${r1},0,${arc},0,${point(r1, d0)}`,
        'Z',
    ].join('')
}

/**
 * Segment Function.
 * 
 * Modified version of Håken Lid's SVG circle segments.
 * 
 * @see https://observablehq.com/@haakenlid/svg-circle
 * @see https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/#arcs-circles
 */
function segment(i, segments, size, radius, width, margin, className, fillColor) {
    const center = size/2
    const degrees = 360 / segments
    const start = degrees * i
    const end = (degrees * (i + 1 - margin) + (margin == 0 ? 1 : 0))
    const path = segmentPath(center, center, radius, radius-width, start, end, i);  
    const el = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path' );
    el.setAttribute(
        'd',
        path
    );
    el.classList.add( 'path-segment', className );
    el.style.fill = fillColor;

    return el;
}

/**
 * Render.
 * 
 * Function that will render the svg circle.
 */
function render(circleDiv, stroke = 20) {
    if ( null !== circleDiv ) {

        // Setup environment.
        const svgSize = 580
        const segments = 6
        const segmentWidth = 60
        const strokeWidth = stroke
        const margin = (stroke === 0 ? 0.1 : 0)
        const strokeColor = '#fff'
        const outerFill = '#FB8D00'
        const middleFill = '#E68E36'
        const innerFill = '#F9B46F'

        // Set cirlce div attributes.
        circleDiv.style.height = svgSize + 'px';
        circleDiv.style.width = svgSize + 'px';
        circleDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${ 360/2 }deg)`
        circleDiv.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%'

        // SVG NS.
        const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        // Create the <svg>.
        const svg = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'svg' )
        svg.setAttribute( 'viewbox', `0 0 ${svgSize} ${svgSize}` );
        svg.setAttribute( 'overflow', 'visible' );

        // Start the lines variables.
        const center = svgSize/2
        const degrees = 360/segments

        // Attach the children nodes.
        for ( let i = 0; i < segments; i++ ) {
            // Create the first <g>.
            let n = i + 1,
                radius1 = svgSize/2,
                radius2 = svgSize/2 - segmentWidth + 1,
                radius3 = svgSize/2 - ( segmentWidth * 2 ) + 2,
                g1 = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'g' );
            g1.classList.add( 'segment', `segment-${n}` );
            g1.setAttribute( 'data-segment-number', n );
            
            // Attach segments to the <g>.
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius1, segmentWidth, margin, 'outer', outerFill ) );
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius2, segmentWidth, margin, 'middle', middleFill ) );
            g1.appendChild( segment( i, segments, svgSize, radius3, segmentWidth, margin, 'inner', innerFill ) );

            // Start the interior lines.
            if ( i > 0 ) {
                let start = degrees * i
                let [lineX1, lineY1] = polarToCartesian(center, center, radius1, start)
                let [lineX2, lineY2] = polarToCartesian(center, center, radius3 - segmentWidth, start);

                // Attach the segment line.
                let segLine = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'line' )
                segLine.setAttribute( 'stroke', strokeColor );
                segLine.setAttribute( 'stroke-width', strokeWidth );
                segLine.setAttribute( 'x1', lineX1 )
                segLine.setAttribute( 'y1', lineY1 )
                segLine.setAttribute( 'x2', lineX2 )
                segLine.setAttribute( 'y2', lineY2 )
                svg.appendChild( segLine );
            }       
                    
            // Attach the <g> to the <svg>
            svg.appendChild( g1 );

            // Create event handlers with the g1.
            g1.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                const segNumber = this.getAttribute( 'data-segment-number' );

                // Hide bodies.
                const bodies = document.getElementsByClassName( 'segment-body' )
                for ( let i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( ! bodies[i].classList.contains( 'hide' ) ) {
                        bodies[i].classList.add( 'hide' );
                    }
                }

                // Show correct body.
                const body = document.getElementById( 'segment-body-' +  segNumber);
                body.classList.remove( 'hide' );
            });
        }

        // Create and attach line zero.
        const line0 = document.createElementNS( svgns, 'line' );
        const [lineX1, lineY1] = polarToCartesian( center, center, svgSize/2-segmentWidth+1 + segmentWidth, 0 )
        const [lineX2, lineY2] = polarToCartesian( center, center, (svgSize/2-(segmentWidth*2)+2 - segmentWidth), 0 );

        line0.setAttribute( 'stroke', strokeColor );
        line0.setAttribute( 'stroke-width', strokeWidth/2 )
        line0.setAttribute( 'x1', lineX1 )
        line0.setAttribute( 'y1', lineY1 + ( ( strokeWidth/2 ) / 2 ) )
        line0.setAttribute( 'x2', lineX2 )
        line0.setAttribute( 'y2', lineY2 + ( ( strokeWidth/2 ) / 2 ) )
        svg.appendChild( line0 );

        // Attach to div.
        circleDiv.append( svg );
    }   
}

// Attach render to onload.
const circleDiv = document.getElementById( 'interactive-circle-svg' );
const circleDiv2 = document.getElementById( 'interactive-circle-svg2' );
window.onload = render(circleDiv, 40); // 40px lines
window.onload = render(circleDiv2, 0); // 0.1 margins
```

```html
<div id="interactive-circle-svg"></div>
<div id="interactive-circle-svg2"></div>
```